# Dual monitor with different Applications. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, application-switcher, dualhead

There is a way in Ubuntu 14.04 to work with two different screens while the set of applications of each screen is individual, so alt+tab would not show all applications, but only the ones belonging in the specific screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no feature like this built in to Unity. There are three alternative options:

- Run two X sessions, one outputting to each monitor, but you can only have your keyboard and mouse connected to one xserver, and will have to configure the other to be accessed remotely. See [How to run two X sessions at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9694/how-to-run-two-x-sessions-at-the-same-time)
- Run VirtualBox or KVM full-screen on one monitor. 3D speed on the guest monitor will be reduced. You can avoid this if you have two different graphics cards, and configure PCI pass-through and then run two guest VMs, each connected directly to one graphics card, and hence one monitor. The downside of this approach is that to share files between the two operating systems you would have to export a shared directory between them. The main downside, though, is that it is tricky to set up and has problems with some hardware. See [How to use NVIDIA GeForce M310 on Ubuntu 12.10 running as guest in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox) (the answer is not specific to either Nvidia or Ubuntu 12.10) and also [The VGA passthrough club - did you succeed, and how?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111175)
- Use a desktop that supports assigning a workspace to a monitor, see [Switch workspaces individually on each monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126100/switch-workspaces-individually-on-each-monitor)

Comment: That is a very complete answer. Thank you. I did not upvoted because the lack of reputation.